# ASP.NET Core MVC & C# - redirect to same view ( action ) when changing language using culture

Tags: razor, asp.net-core-mvc, culture

I have localization in my project. What I want is to whenever a user changes language it redirects him to the same page he was in. But now I always redirect him to the `Index` page.

View (layout) :

```
<a asp-controller="language" asp-action="change" asp-route-culture="en-GB" class="btn btn-clear primary"›
<i class="fas fa-globe-americas mx-1" title="Arabic"></i>@sharedResource["arabic"]
</a›
‹a asp-controller="language" asp-action="change" asp-route-culture="en-US" class="btn btn-clear-primary"›
<i class-"fas fa-globe-americas mx-1" title="English"›</i>English
</a›
```

Controller (languageController):

```
public IActionResult Change( string culture)
{
    Response.Cookies.Append (CookieRequestCultureProvider.DefaultCookieName,
                             CookieRequestCultureProvider.MakeCookieValue(newRequestCulture(culture)),
    new CookieOptions ( Expires = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.AddMonths(1)}
):

    Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture(culture);
    Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture=CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture(culture);
    //But independent of language, keep datetime format same
    DateTimeFormatInfo englishDateTimeFormat = new CultureInfo("en-CA").DateTimeFormat;
    Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat=englishDateTimeFormat;

    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
}
```

How can I redirect the user to the same page that he changes the language inside it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do this and it works for me.

```
public IActionResult Change(string culture)
{
    Response.Cookies.Append (CookieRequestCultureProvider.DefaultCookieName,
                             CookieRequestCultureProvider.MakeCookieValue(newRequestCulture(culture)),
    new CookieOptions ( Expires = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.AddMonths(1)}
);

    Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture(culture);
    Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture=CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture(culture);
    //But independent of language, keep datetime format same
    DateTimeFormatInfo englishDateTimeFormat = new CultureInfo("en-CA").DateTimeFormat;
    Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat=englishDateTimeFormat;

string referer = Request.Headers["Referer"].ToString();
string action = referer.Substring(referer.LastIndexOf("/")+1,referer.Length-referer.LastIndexOf("/")-1);
string afterRemoveAction = referer.Substring(0, referer.LastIndexof("/") );
string controller = afterRemoveAction.Substring(afterRemoveAction.LastIndexOf("/")+1,
afterRemoveAction.Length-afterRemoveAction.LastIndexOf("/")- 1);
return RedirectToAction(action, controller);
}
```